# stacked barplot based color

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

I would like to have a stacked barplot like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu8A0.png) but where the color is different for each bar such as in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EJeJ.png)  with the stack line.

```
x<-matrix(runif(40),ncol=10)
barplot(x,legend=c('part1','part2','part3','part4'), col=rainbow(10))
```

[image: tacked plot with the wrong color]
[image: bar plot with good colors but without the stack]

Comment: possible duplicate of [different colors for each bar in stacked bar graph - base graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781685/different-colors-for-each-bar-in-stacked-bar-graph-base-graphics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in base graphics. But if you are willing to use `ggplot2`, it's pretty easy to do. You can for example use the transparency and the color as two distinct things you would like to change. Here's the code I used.

```
require(ggplot2)
# defining the data
set.seed(1)
x<-matrix(runif(40),ncol=10)
df <- data.frame(x=factor(rep(1:ncol(x), each=nrow(x))), 
                 y=as.numeric(x), 
                 part=factor(paste0("part", 1:nrow(x)), levels=paste0("part", nrow(x):1)))
# ggplot call...
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x, alpha=part)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_bw(base_size=30) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name="", breaks=NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="", guide="none") +
  scale_alpha_discrete(name="", range=c(.3,1))
```

This gives you the following figure.
[image]

Of course you can then change the colors and transparencies at will. Just change the `scale_alpha_discrete` and `scale_fill_discrete` function calls.