# Barplot with defined colour per bar

Tags: r, plot

I have this data (matrix)

```
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
     [1,] 0.02 0.03 0.03 0.05
     [2,] 0.00 0.00 0.04 0.00
     [3,] 0.00 0.00 0.03 0.00
     [4,] 0.00 0.00 0.06 0.00
     [5,] 0.00 0.00 0.07 0.00
```

I have tried different compbinations of colours non of them works.

I would like to have the first 2 bars to be in `blue`, the third to be in these colours

```
colr <- c("red","yellow","green","yellow","red")
```

and last column in `blue`

I have tried even to define matrix of colours:

```
colr <- cbind(c("blue","white","white","white","white"),
              c("blue","white","white","white","white"),
              c("red","yellow","green","yellow","red"),
              c("blue","white","white","white","white"),
              c("blue","white","white","white","white"))

barplot(as.matrix(x), col=colr)
```

Please use only base `R` barplot for solution. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [different colors for each bar in stacked bar graph - base graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781685/different-colors-for-each-bar-in-stacked-bar-graph-base-graphics). Please also provide your data in an easily copy-paste-able format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = as.matrix(x)
graphics.off()
barplot(m, col = "blue")
barplot(replace(m*0, cbind(1:NROW(m), 3), m[,3]),
        col = c("red","yellow","green","yellow","red"), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: SO smart with the replacement!

Answer (score 2):

I need to say that this solution is not the piece of programming art, however, it works.

```
mm <- matrix(c(0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.03, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.06, 0.00,0.00, 0.00, 0.07, 0.00), 5, 4, byrow=T)
my.colors <- list(c("blue"), c("blue"), c("red","yellow","green","yellow","red") , c("blue"))
my.ylim <- c(0, max(colSums(mm)))
my.xlim <- c(0, 5)

for(i in 1:4){
    barplot(matrix(mm[,i]), 
            space=(i-1)*1.5, 
            xlim=my.xlim, ylim=my.ylim, 
            col=my.colors[[i]], add=i!=1)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, would solve with looping as well but this to be avoided forgot to mention this.