# Changing colours of individual bars in a stacked barplot R

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked

I have data on infection levels (graded 1-3 by severity) in different cell lines. I have created a stacked barplot but I can only change the colours of all the bars, when I'd like to separate lines by colour. I'd like the 2 WT to have a red palette, the 2 KO a yellow palette and the AB lines a blue palette.

My data looks like this:

[image: My data]

I tried this but it gives me the following graph:

```
inf.level<-read.csv("Infection_level.csv")

cols<-c("darkred", "red", "darksalmon", "darkorange3", "darkorange", "orange", "blue4", "blue", "cornflowerblue")

barplot(as.matrix(inf.level), ylab="Tsetse infection (%)", col=cols)]
```

[image: My barplot]

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you :)

EDIT dput(inf.level) :

> structure(list(WT_MG = c(29.41176471, 23.52941176,
>   11.76470588 ), WT_PV = c(21.42857143, 7.142857143, 14.28571429), KO_MG = c(5.555555556, 
>   16.66666667, 33.33333333), KO_PV = c(0L, 0L, 0L), AB_MG = c(0, 
>   28.57142857, 4.761904762), AB_PV = c(0, 0, 5.555555556)), .Names = c("WT_MG",  "WT_PV", "KO_MG", "KO_PV", "AB_MG", "AB_PV"), class =
>   "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -3L))

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(inf.level)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can color the bars individually. I came across a few ideas from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781685/different-colors-for-each-bar-in-stacked-bar-graph-base-graphics).

Would make `cols` a matrix that contains the different color palettes for different bars.

```
cols<-matrix(c(rep(c("darkred", "red", "darksalmon"), 2),
               rep(c("darkorange3", "darkorange", "orange"), 2), 
               rep(c("blue4", "blue", "cornflowerblue"), 2)), 
             ncol = 6, nrow = 3)

inf.level.mat <- as.matrix(inf.level)

barplot(inf.level.mat, ylab="Tsetse infection (%)")

for (i in 1:ncol(inf.level.mat)) {
  x = inf.level.mat
  x[,-i] <- NA
  barplot(x, col = cols[,i], add=TRUE)
}
```

[image: barplot with different color palettes]