# Different colours for each labelled stacked bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-col

How can a stacked bar plot be made such that it has different colours for each segment of each stacked bar (i.e. as many unique colours as total segments across all bars - in this case 7 different colours).

I have tried the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781685/different-colors-for-each-bar-in-stacked-bar-graph-base-graphics), but get different results due to differently formatted input data, and that question showing totals and not requiring the legend (I require the legend).

#### MRE + attempts so far

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(discipline = c("Dev Ops", "Dev Ops", "Dev Ops", 
"Dev Ops", "Data Engineering", "Data Engineering", "Data Engineering"
), work_type = c("Casual/Vacation", "Contract/Temp", "Full Time", 
"Part Time", "Casual/Vacation", "Contract/Temp", "Full Time"), 
    n = c(3L, 117L, 581L, 9L, 1L, 297L, 490L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  discipline       work_type           n
  <chr>            <chr>           <int>
1 Dev Ops          Casual/Vacation     3
2 Dev Ops          Contract/Temp     117
3 Dev Ops          Full Time         581
4 Dev Ops          Part Time           9
5 Data Engineering Casual/Vacation     1
6 Data Engineering Contract/Temp     297
7 Data Engineering Full Time         490
```

This produces the correct stacked bar plot, but with the same colours for both stacked bars

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = discipline, y = n, fill = work_type)) +
    geom_col(position = "Stack")
```

[image]

This applies unique colours to each stacked bar, but applies the *same* to both stacked bars

```
cols <- c("#5E4FA2", "#5E4FA2CC", "#5E4FA299", "#5E4FA266", "#9E0142", 
"#9E0142CC", "#9E014299")
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = discipline, y = n, fill = work_type)) +
    geom_col(position = "Stack") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols[1:4])
```

[image]

This achieves different colours across both stacked bars, but wrong colours (and wrong legend)

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = discipline, y = n, fill = cols)) +
    geom_col(position = "Stack")
```

[image]

This is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22782263/5783745) approach, but note the bar heights match the totals across all bars (rather than for each bar), and also has the same colours in both stacked bars

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = discipline:work_type) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = n)) + 
  geom_col(fill = c(cols, cols))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you want two combine two factors, the usual trick is to use `interaction()` so your code would be:

```
# Data 
df <- structure(list(discipline = c("Dev Ops", "Dev Ops", "Dev Ops", 
"Dev Ops", "Data Engineering", "Data Engineering", "Data Engineering"
), work_type = c("Casual/Vacation", "Contract/Temp", "Full Time", 
"Part Time", "Casual/Vacation", "Contract/Temp", "Full Time"), 
    n = c(3L, 117L, 581L, 9L, 1L, 297L, 490L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))

# Colours
cols <- c("#5E4FA2", "#5E4FA2CC", "#5E4FA299", "#5E4FA266", "#9E0142", 
"#9E0142CC", "#9E014299")

# Plot
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = discipline, y = n, fill = interaction(work_type, discipline))) +
  geom_col(position = "Stack") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Whatever", values = cols)
```

[image: Code output plot]

You might want a better name for the colour legend though, and might want to investigate the `sep` argument to `interaction` so that the factors are a bit more readable.

Comment: Wow - very nice. I was googling along the lines of 'multiple variables in named vector to values argument of scale_fill_manual'  - but `interaction` is much more succinct and seems to achieve a similar end. Thanks for the help!